# Change variable class from Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My goal is to change variables `data class` of uploaded `dataset`. `data class` should be selected by the user in `ui`.

As uploaded `datasets` might be different, I use `lapply` to create `selectInput` for each column in the dataset. Piece of code below generates selectInputs for each column called `variable_i`, where `i` is a number of column.

```
lapply(seq(ncol( rawdata() )),function(i){

            selectInput(inputId = paste0("variable","_",i),label = colnames(rawdata())[i],
                        choices = c("factor", "numeric", "integer", "character"),
                        selected = class(rawdata()[,i])
            )
          })
```

Using this `selectInput` user can input `data class`. 
My question is, how to change class of variables using inputed info from  `input$variable_i` as input names are dynamic and I can't simply call it.

Maybe is there any other approaches to change data class from UI?

Whole code I use below. If the problem will be solved, I'll share full working code.

```
library(summarytools)
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("dplyr")
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output,session) {


#upload file from PC
rawdata <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$fileIn

    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath, sep=input$Separator)

  })




#Get data example
output$DataCheck <- renderTable({

                      head(rawdata())

                      })



#get data summary
output$summaryTable <- renderUI({

  out <- print(dfSummary( rawdata(),graph.magnif = 0.8), style = 'grid', omit.headings = TRUE, method = 'render',bootstrap.css = FALSE)
  out[[3]][[2]][[1]]
})



output$colname_in <- renderUI({

  selectInput(inputId = "colname",
              label = "Choose column",
              choices = c("",colnames(rawdata())),
              selected = "")

})



observeEvent(input$change_class, {

  v$data <- eval(parse(text = paste0('v$data %>% mutate(',
                                     input$colname,
                                     ' = as.',
                                     input$class,
                                     '(',
                                     input$colname,
                                     '))')
  )
  )

})


}
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- bootstrapPage(

  dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "AK47"
                    ), #dashboardHeader

 #Sidebar--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  dashboardSidebar(

      sidebarMenu(
                   id = "tabs",
                   menuItem("Step 1: Input Data", tabName = "Input", icon = icon("cog"))

                  ) #sidebarMenu

    ),#dashboardSidebar



 #Body-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 dashboardBody(

   tabItems(

     tabItem("Input",

           fluidRow(  
             box(width = 4,title = 'Upload your data file:',solidHeader = T,status = 'primary',


                 #Upload file from PC
                 fileInput('fileIn',label = 'Select the data'),

                 #choose separator
                 radioButtons("Separator","Choose separator:", inline = TRUE,
                              choices=c(Comma=",",
                                        Semicolon=";",
                                        Tab="\t"),  selected = ";")

             ) #box
           ), #fluidRiw


           fluidRow(  
             box(width = 12,title = 'Check the data for correct separator:',solidHeader = F ,status = 'primary',

                 tableOutput('DataCheck'),
                 tags$hr()

             ) #box
           ),  #fluidRow

           fluidRow(  
             box(width = 12,title = 'Change variable typesr:',solidHeader = F ,status = 'primary',

                 uiOutput("colname_in"),

                 selectInput(inputId = "class",
                             label = "Choose class",
                             choices = c("", "factor", "numeric", "integer", "character"),
                             selected = ""),

                 actionButton("change_class",
                              "Change class"),

                 uiOutput('summaryTable'),

                 tags$hr()

             ) #box
           )  #fluidRow


     ) #tabItem



   ) #tabItems


      )#dashboardBody  




  )#dashboardPage
)#bootstrapPage

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating one `selectInput` for each column, I would use two `selectInputs`, one for column name, one for class and an action button to change the class.

Here is my approach. It might not be perfect, but could be a start.

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")


shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage(

        # Layout with sidebar
        sidebarLayout(

            ## Sidebar -----
            sidebarPanel(

                # > some example input on sidebar -----

                uiOutput("colname_in"),
                selectInput(inputId = "class",
                            label = "Choose class",
                            choices = c("", "factor", "numeric", "integer", "character"),
                            selected = ""),
                actionButton("change_class",
                             "Change class")

            ), # closes Sidebar-Panel



            # Main-Panel ------
            mainPanel(


                             tableOutput("print")





            )  # closes mainPanel                      

        ) # closes sidebarLayout

    ), # closes fluidPage


    # Server ------
    server = function(input, output, session){

        v <- reactiveValues(data = iris)


        output$colname_in <- renderUI({

            selectInput(inputId = "colname",
                        label = "Choose column",
                        choices = c("",colnames(v$data)),
                        selected = "")

        })

        observeEvent(input$change_class, {

            v$data <- eval(parse(text = paste0('v$data %>% mutate(',
                                     input$colname,
                                     ' = as.',
                                     input$class,
                                     '(',
                                     input$colname,
                                     '))')
                               )
                 )

        })



        output$print <- renderTable({

            print(input$colname)
            print(input$class)
            print(input$change_class)

                v$data

        })

    } # Closes server
) # Closes ShinyApp
```

---

**Update**
Below I integrated my approach into your code. It is important to read the csv into the reactiveValue v$data which works inside an observeEvent.

```
library("summarytools")
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("dplyr")
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output,session) {


    #upload file from PC
    v = reactiveValues(path = NULL)


    observeEvent(input$fileIn, {
        req(input$fileIn)
        v$data <- read.csv(input$fileIn$datapath, sep = input$Separator)


    })




    #Get data example
    output$DataCheck <- renderTable({

        req(v$data)
        head(v$data)

    })



    #get data summary
    output$summaryTable <- renderUI({

        req(v$data)

        out <- print(dfSummary(v$data,graph.magnif = 0.8), style = 'grid', omit.headings = TRUE, method = 'render',bootstrap.css = FALSE)
        out[[3]][[2]][[1]]

    })



    output$colname_in <- renderUI({

        req(v$data)

        selectInput(inputId = "colname",
                    label = "Choose column",
                    choices = c("",colnames(v$data)),
                    selected = "")

    })



    observeEvent(input$change_class, {

        v$data <- eval(parse(text = paste0('v$data %>% mutate(',
                                           input$colname,
                                           ' = as.',
                                           input$class,
                                           '(',
                                           input$colname,
                                           '))')
        )
        )

    })


}
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- bootstrapPage(

    dashboardPage(

        dashboardHeader(title = "AK47"
        ), #dashboardHeader

        #Sidebar--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        dashboardSidebar(

            sidebarMenu(
                id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Step 1: Input Data", tabName = "Input", icon = icon("cog"))

            ) #sidebarMenu

        ),#dashboardSidebar



        #Body-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        dashboardBody(

            tabItems(

                tabItem("Input",

                        fluidRow(  
                            box(width = 4,title = 'Upload your data file:',solidHeader = T,status = 'primary',


                                #Upload file from PC
                                fileInput('fileIn',label = 'Select the data'),

                                #choose separator
                                radioButtons("Separator","Choose separator:", inline = TRUE,
                                             choices=c(Comma=",",
                                                       Semicolon=";",
                                                       Tab="\t"),  selected = ";")

                            ) #box
                        ), #fluidRiw


                        fluidRow(  
                            box(width = 12,title = 'Check the data for correct separator:',solidHeader = F ,status = 'primary',

                                tableOutput('DataCheck'),
                                tags$hr()

                            ) #box
                        ),  #fluidRow

                        fluidRow(  
                            box(width = 12,title = 'Change variable typesr:',solidHeader = F ,status = 'primary',

                                uiOutput("colname_in"),

                                selectInput(inputId = "class",
                                            label = "Choose class",
                                            choices = c("", "factor", "numeric", "integer", "character"),
                                            selected = ""),

                                actionButton("change_class",
                                             "Change class"),

                                uiOutput('summaryTable'),

                                tags$hr()

                            ) #box
                        )  #fluidRow


                ) #tabItem



            ) #tabItems


        )#dashboardBody  




    )#dashboardPage
)#bootstrapPage

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see that you use `v <- reactiveValues(data = iris)`, however, my original approach is `v <- reactive(iris)`. Because of this, `eval` is not suitable if I understand correctly?

Comment: I think it’s the assignment which is causing problems with your reactive. You can‘t assign a value to a reactive but you can write a value into a reactiveValue.

Comment: Changing the reactive into a reactiveValue should not cause problems in your code.

Comment: I'm unable to use your example. Maybe I'm missing something?
My goal is to get final `dataframe` which will be used for other calculations.
See my full code for data reading and checking:
https://pastebin.com/eDFjJaU4
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Strange, here it is working. v$data would be your final dataframe that you should be able to use in further calculations. In my example  I just put it in a renderTable to show the output. I can, for example, recode Species as integer and will get a row of NAs in the Species column.

Comment: Have you tried to run my example code and does it throw an error?

Comment: Not sure how to apply your code without changing whole structure of my code. Update my code with necessary packages: https://pastebin.com/rihEVNPJ

Comment: I am not in an environment where I can access pastebin.com (firewall). I'll give it a look later.

Comment: Really nice job, thanks a lot @TimTeaFan!
Slightly update your code in order to selection of `Separator` work properly.